# Equivalent of this Xamarin MVVMLight using SimpleIoc container to Xamarin Prism DryIoc

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, prism, dryioc

Below are code from Xamarin MVVMLight using SimpleIoc container and now i am porting it to Xamarin Prism using DryIoccontainer :

```
this.container.Register<IAsciiCommander>(() =>  {
      var commander = new AsciiCommander();
      commander.AddSynchronousResponder();
      commander.AddResponder(
          this.container.GetInstance<TranspondersMonitor>());
      commander.AddResponder(
          this.container.GetInstance<BarcodeMonitor>()); 
      return commander;
  });
```

The following is some in ViewModelLocator and I need to do this in App.xaml.cs

```
 this.container.Register<InventoryConfiguration>(true);
 this.container.Register<IInventoryConfigurator>(
     () => new InventoryConfigurator(
              this.container.GetInstance<IAsciiCommander>(),
              this.container.GetInstance<InventoryConfiguration>())
 );// This is done in ViewModelLocator
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about Prism, but the respected registrations in DryIoc would be:

```
this.container.RegisterDelegate<IAsciiCommander>(r => { 
    var commander = new AsciiCommander();
    commander.AddSynchronousResponder();
    commander.AddResponder(r.Resolve<TranspondersMonitor>());
    commander.AddResponder(r.Resolve<BarcodeMonitor>());
    return commander; });
```

2nd snippet:

```
this.container.Register<InventoryConfiguration>();
this.container.RegisterDelegate<IInventoryConfigurator>(r => 
    new InventoryConfigurator(
        r.Resolve<IAsciiCommander>(), 
        r.Resolve<InventoryConfiguration>())
 );// This is done in ViewModelLocator
```

Regarding `true` parameter there is no such in DryIoc. You may immediately Resolve the service after registration, but I think that would make sense only if service is singleton (`Reuse.Singleton` parameter in DryIoc).

By immediately resolving I mean just call a `Resolve` ignoring the result, so that singleton will be instantiated and stored in container singletons scope.

Comment: the first snippet have not error but the second one did but when i changed Register to RegisterDelegate no error.                                                                                     this.container.Register<InventoryConfiguration>();
this.container.RegisterDelegate<IInventoryConfigurator>(r => 
    new InventoryConfigurator(
        r.Resolve<IAsciiCommander>(), 
        r.Resolve<InventoryConfiguration>())
 );    I will test it if it will do what supposed to do........Thanks for quick reply

Comment: My viewmodel is still not working yet and i dont know if it is from the snippet or not but how do i tell container to register a type with immediate creation of the of it instance.....as it is done here in mvvmlight simpleioc below                                                         this.container.Register<ReaderInformation>();
            this.container.Register<ReaderInformationProvider>(true);                             That true tell the container to immediate create  the instance of that type

Comment: Yeah, fixed the Register to RegisterDelegate in a second snippet.

Comment: I registered models like this  containerRegistry.GetContainer().Register<BarcodeInventory>();                 containerRegistry.GetContainer().Register<TransponderInventory>();          
  and i want to do constructor injection and  Now i am getting this error "DryIoc.ContainerException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>" and view refused to load,so i am thinking i dont register my models well since they didnt have Interface.

Comment: regarding true parameter suggestions: the service is singleton and can u give me example on how to achieve immediately resolving after service is registered.....Thanks as always

Comment: that was what i did.......i have resolved them week ago...........thanks